# DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I get the following error in my reportviewer report when I upgraded from Visual Studio 2015 Community to Visual Studio 2017 Community.

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.LocalProcessingException: 'An error occurred during local report processing.'

Inner Exception
DefinitionInvalidException: The definition of the report '' is invalid.

Comment: What is the full exception? I suspect that some NuGet package is missing, check those.

Comment: +  InnerException {"The definition of this report is not valid or supported by this version of Reporting Services. The report definition may have been created with a later version of Reporting Services, or contain content that is not well-formed or not valid based on Reporting Services schemas. Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2016/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded."} System.Exception {Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Please verify that you have installed the following nuget packages.

For Winforms :
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.Winforms/140.340.80

For ASP.NET : 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/140.340.80/

You might also need to install the Report Designer :

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SqlReportingServices.MicrosoftRdlcReportDesignerforVisualStudio-18001

If it does not work, click "continue" in Visual Studio debugger when you get the exception and go see on the Web page what are the error details.

Comment: The correct Winforms nuget package was not installed, thank you!

Comment: Always downloaded latest versions of these packages

Answer (score 4):

this error occurred for not installing correct packages. I have solved this problem by installing latest reportviewer control from this link

```
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportViewerControl.WebForms/150.900.148
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to add that my cause was that the report definition was indeed invalid.

It had syntax errors in some of the expressions.

fixed the rdlc file and the error disappeared, bit of a red herring but ill add this answer for anyone else still suffering the pain of working with microsoft reporting 2005 in 2021 :D

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was installed but I forgot this:

[image]

Hope it helps.